# Share files between 2 computers via bluetooth from terminal

Tags: usb, windows, bluetooth, console, sharing

I have two adjacent computers one running linux with console mode and one with windows 10. I want to transfer files between the two, and they both have bluetooth capabilities. At first, I thought of plugging a usb and perform the following procedure:

```
fdisk -l
mount /dev/sdc1 /media
mkdir /media/myfiles01
cp ~/file1 ~/file2 /media/myfiles01
cd ~
umount /dev/sdc1
```

And then, I would remove the usb device and plug it into the other computer, and transfer the files to it; But I thought, why don't I use bluetooth to share files directly?

Can I use bluetooth from terminal as I have no GUI on that computer? I have no prior experience in this, so if it is possible, I need detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to `apt install bluez-tools obexpushd`.

To send and receive files, you need to set up and pair the devices first.

### SETUP

---

[from Arch Wiki - bluetooth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth):

## Bluetoothctl

Start the `bluetoothctl` interactive command. There one can input `help` to get a list of available commands.

- Turn the power to the controller on by entering `power on`. It is off
  by default.
- Enter `devices` to get the MAC Address of the device with
  which to pair.
- Enter device discovery mode with `scan on` command if
  device is not yet on the list.
- Turn the agent on with `agent on`.
- Enter `pair MAC Address` to do the pairing (tab completion works).
- If using a device without a PIN, one may need to manually trust the
  device before it can reconnect successfully. Enter `trust MAC Address`
  to do so.
- Finally, use `connect MAC_address` to establish a connection.

*The last two bullet points are not necessary for the send part of a file transfer, but you need the `connect` later for the receive part.*

An example session may look this way:

```
# bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 00:10:20:30:40:50 pi [default]
[bluetooth]# agent KeyboardOnly 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent 
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:10:20:30:40:50 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 myLino
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 LegacyPairing: yes
[bluetooth]# pair 00:12:34:56:78:90
Attempting to pair with 00:12:34:56:78:90
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 00:12:34:56:78:90
Attempting to connect to 00:12:34:56:78:90
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

To make changes permanent and in order to have the device active after a reboot, a `udev` rule is needed:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

```
# Set bluetooth power up
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", RUN+="/usr/bin/hciconfig %k up"
```

**Tip**: Replace `KERNEL=="hci0"` with `KERNEL=="hci[0-9]*"` to match all BT interfaces.

After a suspend/resume-cycle, the device can be powered on automatically using a custom systemd service:

`/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth-auto-power@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth auto power on
After=bluetooth.service sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-%i.device suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hciconfig %i up

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Enable an instance of the unit using your bluetooth device name, for example `bluetooth-auto-power@hci0.service`.

---

Now your devices are paired. Check that you can see the other with `bt-device -l`.

### SEND

Next, you have to send up your `systemd` infrastructure for the send to work, otherwise you get the following error:

```
Acquiring proxy failed: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.bluez.obex: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.LoadFailed: Unit dbus-org.bluez.obex.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Make the necessary `systemd` changes with

```
systemctl --user start obex
sudo systemctl --global enable obex
```

This makes sure you can send files. A `sudo` also in the first line **will fail**!

You can send files now by `bluetooth-sendto --device=12:34:56:78:9A:BC filename filename2`. If a transfer hangs at 100%, a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> finalizes it (or aborts earlier).

To know your device name (12:34:56:78:9A:BC), you can issue `bt-device -l`.

### RECEIVE

---

[from Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=963751#p963751):

We want to set up a OBEX push server, this is why `obexpushd` was needed.

The compatibility flag on the Bluetooth daemon is needed, you have to edit `/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service` with the editor of your choice by adding the `-C` flag to the end of the `ExecStart=` line. It should look like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
```

Reboot or restart the service with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after editing. Choose a specific directory where received files are placed, for example by `sudo mkdir /bluetooth`.

Start the server with `sudo obexpushd -B -o /bluetooth -n`, it should respond with:

```
obexpushd 0.11.2 Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Hendrik Sattler
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions.
Listening on bluetooth/[00:00:00:00:00:00]:9
```

If that's not working, and you get:

```
obexpushd 0.11.2 Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Hendrik Sattler
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions.
BtOBEX_ServerRegister: Address already in use
net_init() failed
```

it could be because you have another daemon or program running which occupies the rfcomm channel 9 that `obexpushd` uses by default. In this case, change the channel to 23 like this:

```
sudo obexpushd -B23 -o /bluetooth -n
```

to use channel 23.

Once you get `obexpushd` running, open a second terminal window. You can verify that the OBEX service is registered with

```
sudo sdptool browse local
```

It should list (at channel 23 in this case), among others, this:

```
Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service Description: a free OBEX server
Service Provider: obexpushd
Service RecHandle: 0x10005
Service Class ID List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 23
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
    Version: 0x0100
```

In that window, while `obexpushd` is still running, use `bluetoothctl` to set `discoverable on`. Now pair from your other device. Pairing MUST be done while `obexpushd` is running, or the other device wont recognize the service is available. If the phone is already paired, remove it from your other device, use `bluetoothctl` to remove it from the Ubuntu computer, and re-pair.

After you connect (the last bullet point from the above list), you should be able to receive files. They will appear in the `/bluetooth` directory. Notice that they will be owned by root, so you'll need sudo to access them. Or you can do a `chmod 0777 /bluetooth` for a public exchange directory, since the bluetooth authentification is device-based and not user-based anyway.

In order to automate the obexpushd command, create the file `/etc/systemd/system/obexpush.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=OBEX Push service
After=bluetooth.service
Requires=bluetooth.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/obexpushd -B23 -o /bluetooth -n

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, set that to autostart with

```
sudo systemctl enable obexpush
```

After a reboot or restart  of the service with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, you should be able to send and receive files in both directions now.

Don't forget to connect the devices when trying to receive files.

Comment: These instructions were double-checked with an android phone and a Ubuntu laptop. Setup, send and receive confirmed to work.

Comment: Careful: `/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service` is most probably a symlink to `/lib/systemd/...`, and you don't want to modify this one. You should use an override: create the `/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service.d` directory and put a file in there ending in `.conf` (like `add-compat-flag.conf`), containing only:
`[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C` (with proper line feeds of course)